# Refining a double many-to-many JOIN

Tags: sql, many-to-many, inner-join

I've got a many-to-many **accounts** <-> **users** relationship. I'm trying to pull all the accounts shared by me and another user. So far I have something I modified from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3267635/165673) answer:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM user
    JOIN account_user ON account_user.user_id = user.id
    JOIN account ON account.id = account_user.account_id
   WHERE user.id IN ({my_id},{other_user_id})
GROUP BY account.id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user.id) = 2
```

This seems to be on the right track, but the `account_user` table has a 'role' field, and I want to make sure that the record I get back contains the role of the other user, not mine. How would I tweak this to make that happen?

Comment: Could you rephrase that question?

Comment: Is the problem that there are 2 role fields in your result set? If so you can use aliases to allow your select to distinguish them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works under my Oracle and the same basic idea should work under any DBMS:

```
SELECT account.*, role
FROM account
    JOIN account_user ON account_id = account.id AND user_id = :other_user_id
WHERE
    account.id IN (SELECT account_id FROM account_user WHERE user_id = :my_id)
```

In plain English:

- Join `account` and `account_user` for the other user.
- Accept only those accounts that are *also* connected to my user.

You can easily join `user` on top of that if you need to (as indicated by your SQL, but not by your question).

Comment: Branko- Awesome! So very clean, and it worked- love it. (I had to specify `account.id` rather than just `id` in my system as was getting an ambiguity error...)

Answer (score 1):

In my example, 'user2' is the other user, 'user1' is you:

```
-- query should work in most RDBMS
SELECT A1.account,
       AU1.role AS user_2_account_role,
       U1.uname AS user_2_name
FROM @account AS A1
JOIN @account_users AS AU1 ON AU1.account_id = A1.id
JOIN @user AS U1 ON U1.id = AU1.user_id
WHERE EXISTS(
    -- get accounts that are 'mine'
    SELECT *
    FROM @user AS U2
    JOIN @account_users AS AU2 ON AU2.user_id = U2.id
    WHERE U2.uname = 'user1' -- 'mine'
    AND AU2.account_id = AU1.account_id
)
AND U1.uname = 'user2' -- other user
```

Sample Data I prepared in SQL Server:

```
-- sample data in SQL SERVER
DECLARE @user TABLE(uname VARCHAR(20), id INT);
INSERT INTO @user(uname, id) 
VALUES('user1', 1),
      ('user2', 2),
      ('user3', 3),
      ('user4', 4);

DECLARE @account TABLE(account VARCHAR(20), id INT);
INSERT INTO @account(account, id)
VALUES('account1', 1),
      ('account2', 2),
      ('account3', 3),
      ('account4', 4);

DECLARE @account_users TABLE(account_id INT, user_id INT, role VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @account_users(account_id, user_id, role)
VALUES(1, 1, 'user1_role'),
      (1, 2, 'user2_role'),
      (2, 1, 'user1_role'),
      (3, 3, 'user3_role'),
      (3, 4, 'user4_role');
```