# MySQL Many-To-Many condition which combine AND/OR

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I have a problem with mysql query, it's complex problem which relates to [Mysql join query for multiple "tags" (many-to-many relationship) that matches ALL tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267609/mysql-join-query-for-multiple-tags-many-to-many-relationship-that-matches-al)

So I have classic MN table schema:

```
Item
1 | Item1
2 | Item2
...

Category
1 | Category1
2 | Category2
3 | Category3
4 | Category4
...

Item_has_category
1 | 1
...
```

And question is - How can I get rows, where *item* has *Category1* **OR** *Category2* **AND** *Category3*?

It is for some complex filter and some categories has a special group, which must be with **AND**.

I suppose that I must combine HAVING with DISTINCT *(link to another questions at top)*, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `group by` would work:

```
select  ItemId
from    Item_has_category
group by
        ItemId
having  sum(case when CategoryId = 1 then 1 end) = 1
        or sum(case when CategoryId = 2 then 1 end) = 1
        andsum(case when CategoryId = 3 then 1 end) = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's work. Now, I must "only" implement it in sofistic generated filter ;( :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Item i
  inner join Item_has_category ic on i.ID = ic.I_ID
  where (ic.C_ID = 1 OR ic.C_ID = 2) AND ic.C_ID = 3
```

Comment: This won't work.  A `where` clause operates on a single row, so `(ic.C_ID = 1 OR ic.C_ID = 2) AND ic.C_ID = 3` can never be true

Comment: Well ofcource... My bad... It's late... I need to go home now :/

Comment: This will never work it is checking for two different values in column using and -1 for that

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

Item

Category

Item_has_category

```
Select * from 
itemcategorymapping icm 
inner join item i on (icm.itemID=i.itemId)
inner join category c on (icm.catId=c.catId)
group by icm.itemId having ((icm.catId=CAT1 or icm.catId=Cat2) AND icm.catID=cat3)
```

Comment: But you can't refer to unaggregated columns in the `having clause`

Answer (score 0):

The idea from Andomar answer is very good and it was breakthrough for me. I propose the upgraded version. It is more elegant and universal way to work with tags groups AND/OR logic. 
It don't needs OR operators, have compact, self-explainable view and easy to generate syntax.

```
SELECT  ItemId
FROM    Item_has_category
GROUP BY
        ItemId
HAVING      SUM(CASE WHEN CategoryId IN (1,2) THEN 1 END) > 0
        AND SUM(CASE WHEN CategoryId IN (3)   THEN 1 END) > 0
        AND SUM(...
```