# Select by tags from different taxonomies (AND + OR)

Tags: mysql, sql, tags, taxonomy

There are filters on the page, where user can select any amount of tags. These tags are grouped by taxonomies. 
On using this kind of filter the selected Articles have to have at least one selected tag from every selected taxonomy. I believe (we can say it for simplicity) we have to select tags between different taxonomies by AND operator, and by OR operator for tags inside one taxonomy.

[image: Filter on page: taxonomyes and Tags]

My tables structure:

**Taxonomies**
fields: id

**Tags**
fields: id, tax_id

**Articles**
fields: id

**ArticlesTags**
fields: id, tag_id, article_id

What MySQL query or queries can I use to get Articles with these filters?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11829617/1056384

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it in 2 queries.

From filter selection we can get id's of taxonomies and tags.
First - we making temp table in which we grouping tags by taxonomy for every Article.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mem_table ( INDEX(article_id) ) ENGINE=MEMORY AS 
    (
        SELECT articletags.article_id, articletags.tag_id, tags.tax_id 
        FROM aricletags
        LEFT JOIN tags
        ON articletags.tag_id=tag.id
        WHERE articletags.tag_id IN (sel_tag1_id, sel_tag2_id, sel_tag3_id...)
        GROUP BY article_id, tax_id"
    );
```

Second -- we search in temp table by taxonomy and every Article must have as many rows as taxonomy groups we have selected in filters.

```
SELECT articels.id
FROM articles
INNER JOIN mem_table
ON mem_table.article_id=article.id
WHERE mem_table.tax_id IN (sel_tax1_id, sel_tax2_id, sel_tax3_id...)                
GROUP BY article.id
HAVING COUNT(article.id) = sel_taxonomy_count
```

Comment: After experiments I found that with Index, which we can create in time of creation memory table, the second query work faster and overall performance of this to queries grows to.