# MySQL - Can it deal with complex "AND" clauses in many-to-many relationships?

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I guess this must be a fairly common problem, but I'm struggling to find an answer.

If I have three tables thus:

```
__POST__

Post_ID    Other_stuff
1
2
3
4
...

__TAG__

Tag_ID    Tag_name
1         MySQL
2         TSQL
3         PGSQL
4         PHP
5         Java
6         VB.NET

__CATEGORY__

Cat_Id    Cat_Description
1         IIS7
2         Apache
3         Oracle
4         NodeJS


__POST_TAG__

Post_ID    Tag_Id
1          2
1          6
2          1
2          4
3          4
3          5
3          1
4          1

__POST_CATEGORY__

Post_ID    Cat_Id
1          1
2          1
2          2
3          1
3          2
```

Is it possible to generate a MySQL query to return only posts tagged with the specified multiple tags and categories?

e.g. in my front end interface, the user would choose "MySQL" and "PHP" tags and "IIS7" and "Apache" categories and my query would return posts 2 and 3 but not the others. The user could potentially choose none or more of each option.

The closest I can get is

```
SELECT
distinct p.* 
FROM posts p 
INNER JOIN post_tag pt on p.Post_Id = pt.Post_Id
INNER JOIN post_category pc on p.Post_Id = pc.Post_Id
WHERE pt.tag_id IN(1,4)
AND ct.cat_id IN(2,3);
```

But this results in an OR query where posts with **either** MySQL **or** PHP tags plus **either** Apache **or** IIS7 are returned, whereas I need a match on all the entered values.

At the moment I'm trying to resist storing tags and categories as a comma delimited string as that seems like very bad practice from a normalisation point of view, but at least that way I could use

```
AND tag like '%MySQL%' AND tag like '%PHP%' AND cat LIKE '%APACHE%'...etc
```

But this seems like a very unsatisfactory solution. Can anyone help me with a better one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql join query for multiple "tags" (many-to-many relationship) that matches ALL tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267609/mysql-join-query-for-multiple-tags-many-to-many-relationship-that-matches-al)

Comment: @PatrickQ - I don't believe this is a duplicate as the need for multiple many-to-many relationships to be fulfilled would, I think, prevent the use of the having count(*) clause as in the solution to that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used MySQL in awhile, but this is kind of a general problem.

The `IN (...)` clause is an `OR` based system.  You've discovered that.

You can use `EXISTS` subqueries, which are much faster than `IN ()` subqueries (supposedly close to join speeds), like so:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM posts p 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM post_tag pt WHERE p.Post_Id = pt.Post_Id AND pt.tag_id = 1)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM post_tag pt WHERE p.Post_Id = pt.Post_Id AND pt.tag_id = 4)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM post_category pc WHERE p.Post_Id = pc.Post_Id AND pc.tag_id = 2)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM post_category pc WHERE p.Post_Id = pc.Post_Id AND pc.tag_id = 3);
```

Notice that you don't need to join if you don't also need the category or tag information returned.

Another option is to use `INTERSECT`, but that's more complicated for the query engine, typically, and probably ends up about as performant as an `IN ()` clause with a subquery.

Comment: I've just given it a quick try and you appear to be a genius. This format should be easy to generate using dynamic SQL in my front end code too. As far as I can tell so far, this is the solution so I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the filters in the `JOIN` clauses does the trick:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p 
INNER JOIN post_tag pt1 on p.Post_Id = pt1.Post_Id AND pt1.tag_id = 1
INNER JOIN post_tag pt2 on p.Post_Id = pt2.Post_Id AND pt2.tag_id = 4
INNER JOIN post_category pc1 on p.Post_Id = pc1.Post_Id AND pc1.cat_id = 2
INNER JOIN post_category pc2 on p.Post_Id = pc2.Post_Id AND pc2.cat_id = 3
```

Which could also be written like this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p 
INNER JOIN post_tag pt1 on p.Post_Id = pt1.Post_Id
INNER JOIN post_tag pt2 on p.Post_Id = pt2.Post_Id
INNER JOIN post_category pc1 on p.Post_Id = pc1.Post_Id
INNER JOIN post_category pc2 on p.Post_Id = pc2.Post_Id
WHERE pt1.tag_id = 1
  AND pt2.tag_id = 4
  AND pc1.cat_id = 2
  AND pc2.cat_id = 3
```