# JOIN query, building up condition in hasMany association

Tags: cakephp, inner-join, has-many-through

I am using CakePHP 2.3.6. In a project, I am using JOIN query in hasMany association, to search some data. My condition should be :

```
User.gender='male' AND User.country='USA'
AND
(Education.level='under_graduate' AND Education.result >= 3.5 AND Education.institute='college 1')
AND
(Education.level='graduate' AND Education.result >= 3 AND Education.institute='college 2')
```

What I tried :

```
$this->paginate['User']['conditions']['AND']['User.gender']='male';
$this->paginate['User']['conditions']['AND']['User.country']='USA';
$this->paginate['User']['joins'][]=array('table'=>'educations','alias'=>'Education','type'=>'INNER','conditions'=>array('Education.user_id=User.id'));
$this->paginate['User']['conditions']['AND'][0]['AND']['Education.result >= ']=3.5;
$this->paginate['User']['conditions']['AND'][0]['AND']['Education.level']='under_graduate';
$this->paginate['User']['conditions']['AND'][0]['AND']['Education.institute']='college 1';
$this->paginate['User']['conditions']['AND'][1]['AND']['Education.result >= ']=3;
$this->paginate['User']['conditions']['AND'][1]['AND']['Education.level']='graduate';
$this->paginate['User']['conditions']['AND'][1]['AND']['Education.institute']='college 2';
```

I generates this condition array :

```
[User] => Array
    (
        [conditions] => Array
            (
                [AND] => Array
                    (
                        [User.gender] => male
                        [User.country] => USA
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [AND] => Array
                                    (
                                        [Education.result >= ] => 3.5
                                        [Education.level] => under_graduate
                                        [Education.institute] => college 1
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [AND] => Array
                                    (
                                        [Education.result >= ] => 3
                                        [Education.level] => graduate
                                        [Education.institute] => college 2
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [joins] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [table] => educations
                        [alias] => Education
                        [type] => INNER
                        [conditions] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Education.user_id=User.id
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

But, when I search using this condition, it returns me an empty result array, but I know there are some in the db that meet these conditions.

So, what is the wrong here ? What should I do ? Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: btw, I found a good one solution in SQL.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267609/mysql-join-query-for-multiple-tags-many-to-many-relationship-that-matches-al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I understand you need to find a user that has two educations. See, in your conditions with AND statement you're trying to find Educations.institute that will be equal to “college 1” and “college 2” in the same time, which is imposible. So, there is a way to find it by adding multiple joins for same table. Like this:

```
    $options['conditions']['User.gender']='male';
    $options['conditions']['User.country']='USA';
    $options['joins'][]=array(
        'table'=>'educations',
        'alias'=>'FirstEd',
        'type'=>'INNER',
        'conditions'=>array('FirstEd.user_id=User.id')
    );
    $options['joins'][]=array(
        'table'=>'educations',
        'alias'=>'SecondEd',
        'type'=>'INNER',
        'conditions'=>array('SecondEd.user_id=User.id')
    );
    $options['conditions']['AND'][0]['FirstEd.result']=3.5;
    $options['conditions']['AND'][0]['FirstEd.level'] = 'under_graduate';
    $options['conditions']['AND'][0]['FirstEd.institute']='college 1';
    $options['conditions']['AND'][1]['SecondEd.result']=3;
    $options['conditions']['AND'][1]['SecondEd.level']='graduate';
    $options['conditions']['AND'][1]['SecondEd.institute']='college 2';

    $this->Paginator->settings = $options;
    $users = $this->Paginator->paginate('User');
```

Not the best solution, but it works for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working here :) . You helped me too much. By the way, why you said that this is not the best solution ? @ccleverketchup

Answer (score 1):

Your query is using all AND statements so can't possibly be fulfilled.
There isn't going to be a row with `Education.level = 'under_graduate'` AND `'Education.level' = 'graduate'` because a field  can't have both values.
You need to add an OR in your query, for example:

```
User.gender='male' AND User.country='USA'
AND
(
    (Education.level='under_graduate' AND Education.result >= 3.5 AND Education.institute='college 1')
    OR
    (Education.level='graduate' AND Education.result >= 3 AND Education.institute='college 2')
)
```

I just added an extra set of brackets and changed the AND to OR between the two clauses relating to Education.
Hopefully you should be able to translate that into CakePHP format and it will work!

Comment: Yeah, I also thought so, that's why right now I am doing this. But, is there any way to do this ? Actually, I need to do that AND, not OR. Do you have any idea ? @EllaRyan

Comment: Sounds like you've got your answer! The query that you were working towards building wouldn't have returned results but I misunderstood your ultimate goal as it wasn't stated in the question.  
Anyway, when you're building queries it can help to check them directly on the DB first to be sure the results are what you expect!

Comment: Yeah, that's true, I should've done it first. Thanks :) @EllaRyan