# SQL tag list and tag filtering

Tags: mysql, sql, tags

I have a SQL database in which I store users and tags associated to users (many to many relationship). I have the classic schema with `users` table, `tags` table and the "bridge" table `usertag` which links users with tags:

```
users table:
    +---------+---------+
    | Id      |  Name   |
    +---------+---------+
    | 1       | Alice   |
    | 2       | Bob     |
    | 3       | Carl    |
    | 4       | David   |
    | 5       | Eve     |
    +---------+---------+

tags table:
    +---------+---------+
    | Id      | Name    |
    +---------+---------+
    | 10      | Red     |
    | 20      | Green   |
    | 30      | Blue    |
    +---------+---------+

usertag table:
    +---------+---------+
    | UserId  |  TagId  |
    +---------+---------+
    | 2       | 10      |
    | 2       | 20      |
    | 1       | 30      |
    | 4       | 20      |
    | 4       | 10      |
    | 4       | 30      |
    | 5       | 10      |
    +---------+---------+
```

Now, I made a query to retrieve all the users and their tags as a comma separated field, using the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function:

```
SELECT u.*, GROUP_CONCAT(ut.tagid) as tags FROM users as u LEFT JOIN usertag as ut ON u.id = ut.userid GROUP BY u.id
```

which gives me the correct output:

```
output:
    +---------+---------+----------+
    | Id      |  Name   | Tags     |
    +---------+---------+----------+
    | 1       | Alice   | 30       |
    | 2       | Bob     | 10,20    |
    | 3       | Carl    | (null)   |
    | 4       | David   | 10,30,20 |
    | 5       | Eve     | 10       |
    +---------+---------+----------+
```

The problem is that now I want to implement tag filtering on top of that, i.e. being able to query the users by tag (or multiple tags). The filter should work using the AND operator.

For example: Get users with tag Red (10) AND Green (20):

```
output:
    +---------+---------+----------+
    | Id      |  Name   | Tags     |
    +---------+---------+----------+
    | 2       | Bob     | 10,20    |
    | 4       | David   | 10,30,20 |
    +---------+---------+----------+
```

Another example: Get users with tag Red (10):

```
output:
    +---------+---------+----------+
    | Id      |  Name   | Tags     |
    +---------+---------+----------+
    | 2       | Bob     | 10,20    |
    | 4       | David   | 10,30,20 |
    | 5       | Eve     | 10       |
    +---------+---------+----------+
```

Another example: Get users with tag Red (10), Green (20) and Blue (30):

```
output:
    +---------+---------+----------+
    | Id      |  Name   | Tags     |
    +---------+---------+----------+
    | 4       | David   | 10,30,20 |
    +---------+---------+----------+
```

How can I implement such query? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267609/mysql-join-query-for-multiple-tags-many-to-many-relationship-that-matches-al) on SO is very similar and it actually works but it doesn't deal with the `GROUP_CONCAT()` field which is something I'd like to keep as it is

Here the SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/291a5c/8

**EDIT**

One may imagine that this query works:

Retrieve all users with tag Red (10) and Blue (20):

```
 SELECT u.name, GROUP_CONCAT(ut.tagid)
    FROM users as u
    JOIN usertag as ut ON u.id = ut.userid
   WHERE ut.tagid IN (10,20)
GROUP BY u.id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ut.tagid) = 2
```

Which gives:

```
output:
    +---------+---------+----------+
    | Id      |  Name   | Tags     |
    +---------+---------+----------+
    | 2       | Bob     | 10,20    |
    | 4       | David   | 10,20    |
    +---------+---------+----------+
```

which username-wise is correct (Bob and David) but the `Tags` field is missing the tag 30 from David's list!

Comment: what's the max number of tags to be checked?

Comment: @vkp it's 16, no more

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`left join` the `tags` table and include the id's being searched for in the join clause and check for counts in `having`.

```
SELECT u.id,u.name,GROUP_CONCAT(ut.tagid) as tags
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN usertag as ut ON u.id = ut.userid 
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.id=ut.tagid AND t.ID IN (10,20,30) --change this as needed
GROUP BY u.id,u.name
HAVING COUNT(ut.tagid) >= COUNT(t.id) AND COUNT(t.id) = 3 --change this number to the number of tags
```

One more option is to use `FIND_IN_SET` if there are limited values. For example,

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT u.*, GROUP_CONCAT(ut.tagid) as tags 
FROM users as u 
LEFT JOIN usertag as ut ON u.id = ut.userid 
GROUP BY u.id
) T
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('10',tags) > 0 AND FIND_IN_SET('20',tags) > 0
```

Comment: ah! ok. Is this something that could run on SQLite? Why  the need to introduce the "tags" table if I don't need the tag names at all?

Comment: it's because you need the counts from that table for comparison.

Comment: Understand. Would you recomend any other schema to simplify further the query? Is this something that could work on sqlite?

Comment: the first query should work in SQLite. the schema you have is apt..don't design a schema to simplify the query.

Comment: This is awesome. But what is `COUNT(ut.tagid) >= COUNT(t.id)` doing? This can never be false if `t.id` is unique or not?