# Need to get all projects from projects table that include all of the provided tag ids WITH SEQUELIZE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sequelize.js

**I need to build a query with Sequelize that performs the following:**

- I have a `projects` table that has `ID` (primary key) among other properties.
- I have a `tags` table that has column `names` and column `ID` (primary key).
- I have a table called `project_tags` that relates both of the previous tables. This table has two foreign keys: `projects.id` and `tags.id`. And relates projects to tags in a One-to-Many way.

**I need to build a Sequelize query that given tag `names`, returns ALL projects that include ALL of the given tag names.**

Example: Providing `foo` and `bar` tag names should return all of the projects that have both of them and not just one or another.

If you are not familiarized with Sequelize but know how to do it with raw SQL query, give me a comment as I can also add raw sql queries with Sequelize.

Comment: project_tags is a link table for many-to-many link. There is enough `project.id` field in `tags` tale for one-to-many link. Are you sure it should be one-to-many?

Comment: You may be right as 1 single project can have many tags and also 1 tag can be assigned to many projects.  @Anatoly

Comment: I finally kind of found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44378087/sql-tag-list-and-tag-filtering